# New (re)design?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, design

I got this on my Safari right now:

[image]

instead of our old design:

[image]

Is it permanent change? Can we somehow influence the design for our site?

Comment: Ew. Looks like thenew SO design, applied to travel. They must be testing it out. The good news it it isn't showing for everyone yet :/

Answer (score 4):

This design is not new. It's skin we use for non-desktop devices. You may want to tap on 'full site' link in footer if you want to see desktop design.

[image: Footer link 'full site']

---

FYI: I'm one of designers on Stack team.

Comment: This is the first time I saw it for a year on iPad.

Comment: And still, can we somehow adjust this design to look more similar to our main site?

Comment: @VMAtm currently we can't. mobile skin is the same for all sites in the network (except Stack Overflow).